# Is there a way to import all English words from a file?

Tags: javascript, import, text-files

I want to make a **Hangman** Game in JavaScript which I need every single every English word, I saw a guy on**GitHub** That uploaded a **.txt** file which has got every **single English word** in a order from top to down, and I wanted to import it **(Staright From My Server Or PC)** And then put it in a if that checks the entered word is similar with the word in the text file, As **[Polymars](https://www.youtube.com/c/Polymars++)** did he made a wordle game in twitter which read that file, I saw so many people saying that it may not load it because of being a such a heavy file. And I really don't know that if it is possible. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please beware that this forum is for technical question as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
All english words seems to be in the ~5MB range, which is a lot, but not beyond modern browsers to compute.
Please clarify where your program must run (only your own pc, from own webserver, hosted elsewhere ...) and please post the code you have tried.
If you are new to JavaScript, i'll suggest you try browsing w3schools.com, and specifically to look into [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think is easier if you use a npm module for that, there are several for that purpose:

- [Wordlist English](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordlist-english)

Comment: yeah i think so